# combine two queries that count by month

Tags: sql

Inspired by [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57692/have-the-new-bounty-changes-caused-more-bounties-to-appear), I wrote two queries on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, one that counts the total number of [Questions Asked by Month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7667/questions-asked-by-month) on SO and another that counts the [Bounties Awarded by Month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7666/bounties-awarded-by-month).  How can I combine them so that I have the output in one query?  I'd like to see
Year, Month, Questions, Bounties, and Amount in one report.

Questions are recorded in the Posts table where PostTypeId = 1, but bounties are recorded in the Votes table where VoteTypeId = 9.

Comment: I can never work out the general way to do this; I end up making a temporary table and modifying it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this in notepad & haven't worked with data explorer on SO.

```
select Isnull(V.Year, P.Year) As Year,
Isnull(V.Month, P.Month) As Month,
Isnull(V.Bounties, 0) As Bounties,
Isnull(V.Amount,0) As Amount ,
P.Questions
FROM
(
select
datepart(year, Posts.CreationDate) Year,
datepart(month, Posts.CreationDate) Month,
count(Posts.Id) Questions
from Posts
where PostTypeid = 1 -- 1 = Question
group by datepart(year, Posts.CreationDate), datepart(month, Posts.CreationDate)
) AS P
left JOIN
(
select
datepart(year, Votes.CreationDate) Year,
datepart(month, Votes.CreationDate) Month,
count(Votes.Id) Bounties,
sum(Votes.BountyAmount) Amount
from Votes
where VoteTypeId = 9 -- 9 = BountyAwarded
group by datepart(year, Votes.CreationDate), datepart(month, Votes.CreationDate)
) AS V
ON P.Year = V.Year AND P.Month = V.Month
order by P.Year, P.Month
```

Comment: This times out when I try to run it in SEDE.  I tried almost *exactly* the same thing before posting this question.  The only difference was that I grouped and ordered by Votes.CreationDate.  At least I know my initial attempt wasn't completely silly if someone else came up with the same thing.  :)

Comment: Looks like you nailed it on the second attempt though.  Thank you!  Do you want to save this on SEDE under your name, or can I just edit the original?

Comment: @Bill: Feel free to add it to SEDE :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Anyone who's interested in the stats can run the query [Bounties and Questions by Month](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/358/bounties-and-questions-by-month).